# Using pytest fixture in test decorator

Tags: python, pytest, decorator, python-decorators, fixtures

i'm writing some unit tests that need to be run in temporary directory, but after performing actions, cwd should be set to original one.
So, to remain consistent with rest of the codebase, i'm using tempfile like:

```
@pytest.fixture   
 def test_dir():  
     with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:  
         yield tmp_dir
```

I thought about using decorator like:

```
def change_dir(dir):
    def wrapper(func):
        def inner(*args,**kwargs):
            origin = os.getcwd()
            os.chdir(dir)
            val = func(*args,**kwargs)
            os.chdir(origin)
            return val
        return inner
    return wrapper
```

But calling it like:

```
@change_dir(test_dir)
def my_test(test_dir):
.....
```

Does not work. I also thought about getting the fixture froms args/kwargs, but it also doesn't seem to work. Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: why don't you just create a second fixture, that chdirs before the yield and goes back after the yield?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the same fixture

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_dir():
    origin = os.getcwd()
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
        os.chdir(tmp_dir)
        yield tmp_dir
        os.chdir(origin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest way:

```
import os
from contextlib import chdir

import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def chdir_tmp_path(tmp_path):
    with chdir(tmp_path):
        yield tmp_path


def test_something(chdir_tmp_path):
    print(os.getcwd())
```

Uses [`contextlib.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.chdir) (new in 3.11) and pytest's own [`tmp_path`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/tmp_path.html#the-tmp-path-fixture) fixture.